# Removing points which deviate too much from adjacent point in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, time-series, data-analysis

So I'm doing some time series analysis in Pandas and have a peculiar pattern of outliers which I'd like to remove. The bellow plot is based on a dataframe with the first column as a date and the second column the data

[image]

AS you can see those points of similar values interspersed and look like lines are likely instrument quirks and should be removed. Ive tried using both rolling_mean, median and removal based on standard deviation to no avail. For an idea of density, its daily measurements from 1984 to the present. Any ideas?

```
auge = pd.read_csv('GaugeData.csv', parse_dates=[0], header=None)
gauge.columns = ['Date', 'Gauge']
gauge = gauge.set_index(['Date'])
gauge['1990':'1995'].plot(style='*')
```

And the result of applying rolling median

```
gauge = pd.rolling_mean(gauge, 5, center=True)#gauge.diff()
gauge['1990':'1995'].plot(style='*')
```

[After rolling median](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k87O2.png)

Comment: You code that made you arrive at that plot?

Comment: @Dark just added, its litteraly just loading in the csv and plotting a reasonable subset of it. The pattern persits throughout though

Answer (score 0):

You can demand that each data point has at least "N" "nearby" data points within a certain distance "D".

- N can be 2 or more.
- nearby for element gauge[i] can be a pair like: gauge[i-1] and gauge[i+1], but since some only have neighbors on one side you can ask for at least two elements with distance in indexes (dates) less than 2. So, let's say at least 2 of {gauge[i-2], gauge[i-1] gauge[i+1], gauge[i+2]} should satisfy: Distance(gauge[i], gauge[ix]) < D
- D - you can decide this based on how close you expect those real data points to be.

It won't be perfect, but it should get most of the noise out of the dataset.